# Is bathing required if puja is done in the evening?

Tags: practice, puja

Typically we bathe in the morning, go to work and come back home in the evening and plan to do Puja. However, it may not be possible to bathe in the evening for reasons like health, timing, water scarcity, etc.

- Is it okay to do Puja without bathing?
- What can we done to "purify" ourselves, is putting Vibhuti solution some other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, physical purity (*suchi*) is a common requirement for doing *pujas* which is done by bathing as water acts as a purifier. But apart from bathing *pranayama* is also an purifier. A simple method for puja is said in Bhagavatam as thus:

> After cleansing oneself, purifying the body by prāṇāyāma, bhūta-śuddhi and other processes, and marking the body with sacred tilaka for protection, one should sit in front of the Deity and worship the Supreme Personality of Godhead. [SB - 11.3.49]

But mental purity is the best. So puja can also be done even without bathing. To do so one can **sprinkle some Ganga water upon himself** and by chanting the following mantra  with mentally remembering Vishnu one can proceed to worship:

> *om apavitraḥ pavitro vā sarvāvasthāṁ gato ’pi vā
>
>   yaḥ smaret puṇḍarīkākṣaṁ sa bahyābhyantara-śuciḥ*

If there is no scope for bathing, even by doing these minimum things one can proceed to do *puja* in the evening.

Comment: It looks like the "apavitrah..." verse is from [this chapter](http://gdurl.com/QMgB) and [this chapter](http://gdurl.com/iIbe) of the Garuda Purana.  Interestingly, in both instances the verse is just said casually, without being prescribed or anything.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, the verse is from Garuda Purana. The mantra is not used as a purifier just because it has been explicitly prescribed there, but because of what it means. The mantra is just a medium, remembering Vishnu is the important thing. Without remembering Him it is only useless to repeat that mantra.

Comment: @BeHappy Yeah, I suppose it's similar in that respect to the Brahmarpanam verse in the Bhagavad Gita, which has been adopted by people as a prayer before meals because of its meaning, despite Krishna not actually prescribing it for that purpose.